# jQuery: referencing and manipulating the parent-element of a dynamically added element

Tags: jquery, dom, fadeout

I'm loading some XML in my document and add a DIV-button to it. By clicking the button, I wan't to `fadeOut()` not only the button, but also its parent element. While referencing and fading out the button itself is working, I fail to get access to its parent-element.  (see the last lines in my code).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var searchstring = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["search"]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.xml',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'xml',
        timeout: 10000,
        error: function(){
            alert('Error loading XML document');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('entry').filter(function(index) { return $('lemma', this).text() == searchstring; } ).each(function() { 
                $(this).find('part_gp > part').each(function(){
                    var more = $('<div class="more">+</div>');
                    $(this).after(more);
                    more.click(fader);
                });

            $( "#result" ).append( $(this) );

            });
            }
    });
});

function fader() {
    $(this).fadeOut();   // this works!!
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(); // this doesn't work!!
}
```

UPDATE:

The XML/HTML will look like this:

```
<part_gp>
  <part>Grafschaft</part>
  <div class="more">+</div>
  <pos> feminin / weiblich</pos>
</part_gp>
```

I want to hide the whole part_gp..

```
$(this).parents("part_gp").fadeOut();
```

didn't work either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `$(this).after()`.  That is putting your button after the block you want to hide, not inside of it.  What you really want is `$(this).append()`.

http://api.jquery.com/after/ 
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how the markup looks like but you can try

```
$(this).parents("div.someClassForIdentification").fadeOut();
```